# Search results duplicated on multiple pages

Tags: support, search

I've noticed that, on some occasions when I search for a tag or other term, a search result will appear on two separate pages.

For example, the post "Example Name" will appear as the x<sup>th</sup> result on page 2, but will then reappear as the x<sup>th</sup> result on page 3.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, seeing one result for the question and one for the answer to that question?

Comment: I didn't think about that. That seems like the most likely reason @femtoRgon

Comment: Look at the beginning of post title in the search results.  It will have "Q" or "A" appended to the front indicating that it is a Question or an Answer.  You can read [How do I search?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to get a better idea of how you can restrict your results to only questions or only answers, and many other options as well

Comment: Thanks @psubsee2003, I will keep that in mind

Comment: Another possibility is that new questions were asked, which pushed some of the results from page 1 to page 2, and so on. This is why "Example Name" might have originally appeared on page 2, but now appears on page 3.

Comment: @PetahChristian I think caching is more to blame for some of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you search without any other search options, you'll find any post in the results, either questions or answers. As answers have no title on their own, the question title is used in the search result.

This makes that, at first glance, you could mistakenly assume a post appeared twice. Visiting the link would however bring you to the post, be it an question or an answer. Also the Q or A at the start of the title indicates what type of post your search criteria matches:

> [image: search result with Q and A]

You can use any of the [search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to limit the results. Adding `is:q` will only give you questions, `is:a` just answers.